# Table data not loading in ASP .NET Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

The Oracle 11g database is connecting fine, but no data is getting displayed in the GridView, Please help! 
**The following code is in page load code**

```
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "DATA SOURCE=DEMODB;USER ID=SYSTEM;password=admin";
        con.Open();
        string sql = "select * from Insurance";
        OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand(sql, con);
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(comm);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Insurance");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Insurance"];
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
```

This is the source code of page:

```
        </asp:Label>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
          ProviderName="<%$ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
          SelectCommand="SELECT &quot;SSN&quot;, &quot;RID&quot;, &quot;EID&quot;, &quot;TYPE&quot;, &quot;COST&quot; FROM &quot;TREATMENT&quot;">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you add more context to this code? For example, where it is called? Page_Load? In a PostBack ? What is code in the aspx page that defines the GridView?

Comment: The above code is in this form load method
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 378px">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT &quot;SSN&quot;, &quot;RID&quot;, &quot;EID&quot;, &quot;TYPE&quot;, &quot;COST&quot; FROM &quot;TREATMENT&quot;"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

Try this in place of your `Page_Load` code and remove the `<asp:SqlDataSource`entirely.

```
DataTable results = new DataTable();
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=DEMODB;USER ID=SYSTEM;password=admin") {
  con.Open();
  using (OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand("select * from Insurance", con)) {
    results.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());
  }
}        
GridView1.DataSource = results;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

The GridView should be as simple as:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: To be honest Ive never used the Oracle Sql providers (Ima SQL Server Guy) but this should roughly represent what you need to do.

Comment: It's working now :-) thanks!! But I didn't understand where was I going wrong?

Comment: In essence you don't need a SQL Data Source AND back-end code, just one or the other. I can't say exactly what was wrong but at a guess the SqlDataProvider wasn't configured correctly and was interfering with your back-end code. I ALWAYS bind from code behind as you tend to have more control and flexibility.